# Meta tags in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

My scenario is such:

In my `/views/layout/default.ctp`

```
<head>
      <!-- other stuff -->
      <?php echo $scripts_for_layout; ?>
</head>
<body>
      <!-- more stuff -->
      <?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>
```

In my `/views/pages/home.ctp`

```
<?php $this->Html->meta('keywords', 'my, keywords', array(), false); ?>
```

However, my problem is that even with `$scripts_for_layout` in my default.ctp, and with `boolean inline = false`, I still can't see the `meta` tag in my `head`, instead I just see them inline.

I am considering the scenario that it `$scripts_for_layout` is echoed before I make that HTML helper call, but surely there must be an elegant way to do this?

Also note that the HTML helper call is the first line to my `views/pages/home.ctp`

**Edit** - Aha I found my mistake. Here's to anybody else who's having the same problem. With CakePHP 1.3, the syntax for the HTML helper changes slightly (and there is no backwards-compatibility for the syntax).

Apparently there's a syntactical flaw in what I wrote in my `view`.
This is the correct way to say `boolean inline = false` in version 1.3:

```
$this->Html->meta("keywords", "keywords, are, sweet", array("inline" => false));
```

Comment: Which version of CakePHP? That's the syntax for 1.2, for 1.3 it's slightly different.

Comment: disregard my answer; I assumed you were trying to output in your layout and had omitted the `echo` !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha I found my mistake. Apparently there's a syntactical flaw in what I wrote in my `view`.
This is the correct way to say `boolean inline = false` in version 1.3:

```
$this->Html->meta("keywords", "keywords, are, sweet", array("inline" => false));
```

Comment: Just for others, you may need to add `<?php echo $this->fetch('meta'); ?>` in the `<head>` section of your layout to get this to work, as described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15112295/1790054).

Answer (score 0):

For CakePHP version 3.x use this in your view:

```
<?php $this->Html->meta('keywords', 'keywords, are, sweet', ['block' => true]); ?>
```

Then in your layout's header use:

```
<?= $this->fetch('meta') ?>
```

The output will be:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="keywords, are, sweet"/>
```