# How to implement og:tag in each post?

Tags: cakephp

In my cakephp project in developer.ctp file i have implemented og:tags. I have done with four types of this. and when i add a new post, at that time i want to implement that each post should have og tags like this:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="discussion" />
<meta property="og:url" content="URL" />
<meta property="og:title" content="any title" />
<meta property="og:image" content="any comment"/>
```

Comment: What does the og: tag look like? What content do you want in it?

Comment: <meta property="og:type" content="discussion" /><meta property="og:url" content="URL" /><meta property="og:title" content="any title" />
<meta property="og:image" content="any comment"/>
so when i add a new post and i want that each of this og:tag will be on the page source.

Comment: @user2106115 please remove your last comment, it's out of line. Be patient or add relevant information, trying to rush people to answer your question is *not* appreciated

Answer (score 3):

In Cakephp 3.x you can simple using this

```
$this->Html->meta(null, null, [
    'property' => 'og:title',
    'content' => 'this is an article title',
    'block' => 'meta']);
```

Result

```
<meta property="og:title" content="this is an article title"/>
```

Comment: GREAT! I used this: `<?php $this->Html->meta(null, $title, ['property' => 'og:title', 'block' => true]); ?>`

Answer (score 2):

To get the meta tags to appear, place this in the header of your default.ctp layout:

```
<?php echo $this->fetch('meta'); ?>
```

Place something like this for each meta tag in the views where you want them to appear:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->meta(array('name' => 'og:type', 'content' => 'discussion'), NULL, array('inline' => false)); ?>
```

Comment: Bill Rollings, i did this but nothing happened.

Comment: OP asked for OG tags, which uses `property` attributes instead of `name` in the meta tag - Facebook's validator complains about this, so this answer isn't technically correct.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a meta tag with a `property` attribute instead of a `name` attribute can be done by passing some specific options to the `meta` helper:

```
$this->Html->meta(array('property' => 'og:title', 'type' => 'meta', 'content' => 'My brilliant page', 'rel' => null));
```